# How to match strings having () or (any characters) java

Tags: java, regex, parentheses

I need a Regular Expression that can match the words that are methods, for example:

`Project.name.toUpper().toBase64()`

matches: `toUpper()` and `toBase64()`

or

`Project.name.toLower(1)`

matches: `toLower(1)`

I already have this but it only matches the first found (toUpper())
in: Project.name.toUpper().toBase64()

```
Pattern patternParenthesis = Pattern.compile("\\(([^)]+)*[)()]*");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
([^.(]+\([^)]*\))
```

- `[^.(]+` matches one or more characters upto next `.` or `(`
- `\([^)]*\)` matches literal `(` then any characters upto next `)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nY8xT7/3)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

```
/\w+\([^$]*?\)/gm
```

https://regex101.com/r/lU8oZ9/1

Answer (score 0):

This one can do the trick :

```
(?<=\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\([0-9,]*\)
```

The lookbehind ( first block inside parentheses) matches the next block  only if preceded by a 'dot'.

The next block ( inside [] ) matches the name of the method ( assuming have only letters/numbers/underscore (can be changed to meet code requirements) ) FOLLOWED BY:

the last parenthesis block captures the () ( with optional 'parameters' inside / again can be changed to meet code requirements )

[image: Demo]

Hope this helps !!